# Получение картинки с сайта в программу C#

Tags: c#

Картинка лежит например по ссылке `dniwe.ru/f/image.png`
Как мне получить данное изображение в `PictureBox`?
А если инет не включен, то чтобы показывалась картинка, которая лежит рядом с программой, у картинки название `image.png`
Вот благодаря помощи вышло такое, но всё равно картинка не появляется:

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap("logo.png");
        pictureBox4.Image = (Image)bitmap;
        var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png");
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        Bitmap loadedBitmap = null;
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            loadedBitmap = new Bitmap(responseStream);
        }
        pictureBox4.Image = (Image)loadedBitmap;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    { 
    
    }
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
```

Comment: нашел что то типо такого   Image img = Image.FromFile("http://www.slilp.ru/images/ec/35/349134/7595.jpg");

Comment: Но не загружает в pictureBox

Comment: @Vlmake: (там комментарии закончились) нет, `catch System.Net.WebException`. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Debuggerом не пользовались??))

Comment: @semenvx27: какой смысл, всё равно не компилируется же.

Comment: а что же выдает при попытке? я подозреваю, что нужно использовать простой catch (Exception ex). по идее с интернета все правильно подтягивается. напишите что за исключение тогда будет яснее

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть решения [с явной загрузкой в code-behind](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511063819/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bryans_tips_and_tricks/archive/2010/12/22/providing-an-initial-image-placeholder-for-the-wpf-image-class.aspx), но я думаю, такой трюк тоже сработает:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" IsAsync="True">
            <Binding.FallbackValue>
                <ImageSource>image.png</ImageSource>
            </Binding.FallbackValue>
        </Binding>
    </Image.Source>
    <Image.Tag>
        <ImageSource>dniwe.ru/f/image.png</ImageSource>
    </Image.Tag>
</Image>
```

Или такой:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="Uri" IsAsync="True"/>
            <Binding Path="LocalFileName"/>
        </PriorityBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

(вам придётся определить свойства `Uri` и `LocalFileName` в `DataContext`, или повторить трюк с `Tag`).

---

Для WinForms решением было бы что-то вроде такого:

```
private Bitmap bitmap; // в классе

//...
bitmap = new Bitmap("image.png");
pictureBox.Image = (Image)bitmap;

try
{
    var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://dniwe.ru/f/image.png");
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    Bitmap loadedBitmap = null;
    using(var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        loadedBitmap = new Bitmap(responseStream);
    }
    pictureBox.Image = (Image)loadedBitmap;
}
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
    // log that the download was not successful
}
```

Возможно, нужно будет сделать асинхронный запрос.

Comment: Ой, только _второй день_? Это задание сложновато для второго дня. У вас есть опыт работы с потоками (threads)?

Comment: @Vlmake: `System.Net.WebException` тогда.

Comment: Ошибка 1 Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "WebException" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?) C:\Users\Общяемся\Desktop\bot\DeBot\DeBot\Form1.cs 47 8 DuvBot

Comment: @Vlmake: используйте простой Exception класс

Comment: @semenvx27: [очень плохой совет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea). Если метод бросает известный тип исключения, его и надо ловить, и не лениться указать правильный тип.

Comment: @VladD: тогда нужно описать каждый из типов Exception. Вот их перечень на операцию http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Comment: @semenvx27: остальные исключения (InvalidOperationException, ProtocolViolationException, NotSupportedException) невозможны в данном контексте, насколько я понимаю.